# Issues in writing test case using PowerMock

Tags: java, junit, powermock, easymock

I am trying to write a test case for checkRegistry method, which is a private method, I am using PowerMock-EasyMock-Juint  to realize this.

Now to test this methods I want to suppress the calls to super calls methods 
eg:

```
intigration = super.getParam("integritycheck");
```

I dont want the call to go to superClass method, but at the same time I want the variable integration to be set.  How do I realize this?

The difficulty is

```
super.getParam("integritycheck");  and 
        sTmpOverride = super.getParam("RESPONSE_OVERRIDE"); will return different results.
```

Method that I am trying to write unit test.

```
private String checkRegistry()
      {
        String intigration = "";
        String sresponse = "";
        try
        {
          try
          {
            intigration = super.getParam("integritycheck");
            sresponse = CustomImpl.getParam("responseWrite");


            **Some Business Logic** 


        sTmpOverride = super.getParam("RESPONSE_OVERRIDE");
        if (sTmpOverride == null) {
            this._bRespOverride = true;
        } else {
            this._bRespOverride = sTmpOverride.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(
                    "true");
        }


        sTmpOverride = super.getParam("ERROR_OVERRIDE");
        if (sTmpOverride == null) {
            this._bErrOverride = true;
        } else {
            this._bErrOverride = sTmpOverride.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(
                    "true");
        }

                    **Some Business Logic** 


          Logging.info("integritycheck  : " + intigration );
          Logging.info("responseWrite   : " + sresponse );
          super.track("Error Directory    : " + sErrorPath);
          }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          _result= false;
        }
        return _result;
      }
```

I am struck on using the below method

```
 suppress(method(CustomRegisterChecker.class, "getParam"));
```

where CustomRegisterChecker.class is the super class.

**UPDATE1:**

```
//Here I am creating a mock for the super class
 CustomRegisterChecker customRegisterMock=createMock(AbstractListener.class);
```

//I am supresssing the calls made to the super class and giving my own response

```
    expect(abstractListenerMock.getParam("integritycheck  ")).andReturn(null);
    expect(abstractListenerMock.getParam("responseWrite")).andReturn(null);
```

But How do I invoke and test the method. I tried using Reflection API. BUT that does not work. it just simply run the program, supressing the super class methods does not happen here.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It looks like it will be an improperly written test. Remember the goal of the unit tests is to actually test your framework, not just to pass. If you're sure this is exactly what you need (there isn't enough info included in the question for me to say), you could try powermock's [partial mocking](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockPartial)

Comment: @blgt I am sorry, I have never written testcases before. What is that you would like to suggest? Kindly specify what more info do you need.

Comment: As I said, could you explain why you need this? (in my experience needing partial mocks usually indicates there's something wrong with the way I've structured the code) You might also check out [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have been asked to write a Test case for it. and I since this is an legacy application I am not supposed to modify it..

Comment: So y no let it call the super?

Comment: @kmanu Super class methods have other parameters which are initailzed again by other helper methods.